# Admob and Facebook Audience Network

Tags: admob, facebook-audience-network

I have an application which is monetized with Facebook Audience Network (FAN). Now i want to add support for Admob because the FAN fill rate is very low. What i want to do is the following:

If FAN fails i want to display Admob ad but i do not want to use the meditation service of Admob because it has problems with the native ads. I simply want to make instance of the Admob ad.

I couldn't find anything about this approach and i simply want to know if it violates the polices?

Comment: Is this for iOS or Android?

Comment: The approach is very standard - it's called a waterfall.  There is no policy violation with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FBAdViewDelegate` methods to track ad events:

```
@interface ViewContorller : UIViewController <FBAdViewDelegate>
```

When a Facebook Audience Network ad fails to load present an AdMob ad:

```
-(void)adView:(FBAdView *)adView didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Ad failed to load");
    // Present AdMob GADBannerView
}
```

If a Facebook Audience Network ad loads hide the AdMob ad:

```
-(void)adViewDidLoad:(FBAdView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"Ad was loaded and ready to be displayed");
    // Hide AdMob GADBannerView
}
```

From [Adding Ad Banners to your iOS app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios-banners).